# How to setup Storybook's storyshots addon with Apollo's MockedProvider

Tags: react-apollo, storybook

The recommended way to render a final state using MockedProvider is to wait for the next tick of the event loop using 'waait'.

But when using the storybook storyshots addon you don't have acces to the test body to inject that wait between the moment you create the tree and the moment you snapshot it.

Because of that, **when snapshots are taken, loading state is what you see there**.

So, how can you make that "wait" happen in order to see the final state?

Comment: Apollo docs about the need to 'waait': https://www.apollographql.com/docs/guides/testing-react-components.html#Testing-final-state

Answer (score 0):

To make the snapshot work with async components, you can set a custom `test` function that awaits for the next render cycle, together with the `jestAsync: true` option.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { create, act } from 'react-test-renderer';
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';
import wait from 'waait';

initStoryshots({
  asyncJest: true,
  test: async ({ story, done }) => {
    let renderer;
    act(() => {
      // React.createElement() is important because of hooks [shouldn't call story.render() directly]
      renderer = create(React.createElement(story.render));
    });

    // Let one render cycle pass before rendering snapshot
    await act(() => wait(0));

    // save all snapshots to the same file (similar to "snapshotWithOptions")
    expect(renderer).toMatchSnapshot();

    done();
  }
});
```

Or if you want to save the snapshots to multiple files:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { create, act } from 'react-test-renderer';
import initStoryshots, { Stories2SnapsConverter } from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';
import wait from 'waait';

const converter = new Stories2SnapsConverter();

initStoryshots({
  asyncJest: true,
  test: async ({ story, context, done }) => {
    let renderer;
    act(() => {
      // React.createElement() is important because of hooks [shouldn't call story.render() directly]
      renderer = create(React.createElement(story.render));
    });

    // Let one render cycle pass before rendering snapshot
    await act(() => wait(0));

    // save each snapshot to a different file (similar to "multiSnapshotWithOptions")
    const snapshotFileName = converter.getSnapshotFileName(context);
    expect(renderer).toMatchSpecificSnapshot(snapshotFileName);

    done();
  }
});
```

More info at https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7745

PS: tested this with `@storybook/react@6.1.18` and `@storybook/addon-storyshots@6.1.18` and `MockedProvider` from `@apollo/react-testing@4.0.0`

Answer (score -1):

When you call initStoryshots, you can pass parameters. So you can use a serializer to do that job with a code similar to this one:

```
import initStoryshots, { multiSnapshotWithOptions } from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';
import wait from 'waait';

initStoryshots({
  framework:'react',
  configPath:'.storybook-snapshots',

  test: multiSnapshotWithOptions({
    serializer: (a) => wait(0).then( () => a )
  })
});
```

The `serializer` config was appearing to me in the docs as root level, but in the code I saw it as an option of the `...SnapshotWithOptions` configs. And it worked fine that way.

The drawback here is that if you do so, you won't see the loading state anymore. But, in my case, I'm thinking about testing it in a normal test.